# SQL using PIVOT right

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a problem, i'm trying to use the PIVOT in my query and without any result. Right now I have a table that looks like:

```
Category     Month    Value
A            August     10
B            August     19
C            August     15
A            September  20
B            September  23
C            September  25
A            October    24
B            October    87
C            October    44
```

I want to make to look in this way:

```
Category      August       September    October
      A       10             20          24
      B       19             23          87
      C       15             25          47
```

In my select is something like:

```
Select cat_name, CAST(month AS VARCHAR(20)), value from dbo.table1.
```

_

```
      select * from (
        select ft.categoryData as [category], CAST(fft.date AS VARCHAR(20)) as [month], tt.value as [value] from firstt ft
                join secondt st on ft.id = st.id
                join thirdt tt on ft.id = tt.type_id
                join fourtht fft on ft.id = fft.category_id
            where ft.date between '2015-07-01' and '2015-09-01' and ft.country = 'EUR'  
group by fft.date, ft.categoryData, tt.value
                ) as t

        PIVOT (

    max(value)
    for [date] in ([jul], [aug], [sept])


      ) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Conditional Aggregate`.

```
select Category,
       max(case when Month = 'August' then Value END) as August,
       max(case when Month = 'September' then Value END) as September,
       max(case when Month = 'October' then Value END) as October
from Yourtable
Group by Category
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df53c/1)

Or use `Pivot`

```
select * 
from Yourtable
pivot (max(Value) For Month in ([August],[September],[October]))pv
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df53c/2)

When the values in month column in unknown the use dynamic sql

```
 declare @sql nvarchar(max)= '',
         @col_list varchar(max)=''

 set @col_list =(select distinct quotename(Month)+',' from yourtable for xml path (''))
 set @col_list  = left(@col_list,len(@col_list)-1)
 set @sql  = '
    select * 
    from yourtable
    pivot (max(Value) For Month in ('+@col_list+'))pv'

    exec sp_executesql @sql
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df53c/5)

Comment: Dear VR46, I updated my question, that's how I did, regarding your answer, but the value are `NULL`

Comment: Dear VR46, now I'm trying to make dynamic version that you created, but the problem is that I have the table like alias `t` and when I `set @col_list`, it does not recognize the table `t`. How to solve it???

Answer (score 1):

By using pivot we can write below query and for syntax follow link  below
 as mentioned

> https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-pivoting-data-in-sql-server-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
PIVOT(MAX(VALUE) FOR MONTH IN (
            [AUGUST]
            ,[SEPTEMBER]
            ,[OCTOBER]
            )) AS
PIVOT_SALES
```

out put is

[image]>

Comment: can u please tell me proper reason for negative mark

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code

```
SELECT * from (SELECT Category, Month, Value 
FROM table1 t) pivot (sum (Value) for Month in ('August', 'September', October') ) order by Category;
```